# UICollectionView Drag and Drop Reorder Items

Tags: ios, swift4

Hello I need solution for one problem Im implementing drag and drop functionality on UICollectionView, but I need some different reorder, will try expla[image]ne with image

problem is when Im trying to change drag 9 and drop it on 4 from position 4 its push every cell with one, but I need to just change places

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is not only change the position of the item being dragged "9", but also change the position of the item that it's in the previous index "4".

When dropping the item "9" in the new position you delete the item from the position it was and insert it in a new position. You might want to store that position and then delete the item "4" from where it is and put it in the previous position of the "9".